# (C++ QT) QList only allows appending constant class objects?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm pretty new to QT. I've been messing with it for a week now. I came across a error while I was trying to add a custom datatype to a Qlist like so

```
QObject parent;

QList<MyInt*> myintarray;

myintarray.append(new const MyInt(1,"intvar1",&parent));
myintarray.append(new const MyInt(2,"intvar2",&parent));
myintarray.append(new const MyInt(3,"intvar3",&parent));
```

and my MyInt class is a simple wrapper for int and looks something like this

```
#ifndef MYINT_H
#define MYINT_H

#include <QString>
#include <QObject>

class MyInt : public QObject
{ 
 Q_OBJECT

 public:

MyInt(const QString name=0, QObject *parent = 0);
MyInt(const int &value,const QString name=0, QObject *parent = 0);
MyInt(const MyInt &value,const QString name=0,QObject *parent = 0);
int getInt() const;

public slots:
void setInt(const int &value);
void setInt(const MyInt &value);

signals:
 void valueChanged(const int newValue);

private:
int intStore;

};

#endif
```

the error i'm getting during the Qlist append

> error: invalid conversion from 'const
>   MyInt*' to 'MyInt*'  error:
>   initializing argument 1 of 'void
>   QList::append(const T&) [with T =
>   MyInt*]'

If anyone can point out what i'm doing wrong, that would be awesome.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So you created a list of:

`QList<MyInt*> myintarray;`

Then you later try to append

```
myintarray.append(new const MyInt(1,"intvar1",&parent));
```

The problem is new const MyInt is creating a const MyInt *, which you can't assign to a MyInt * because it loses the constness.

You either need to change your QList to hold const MyInts like so :

`QList<const MyInt*> myintarray;`

or you need to not create a const MyInt * by changing your appends to:

```
myintarray.append(new MyInt(1,"intvar1",&parent));
```

The method you will choose will depend on exactly how you want to use your QList. You only want const MyInt * if you never want to change the data in your MyInt

Answer (score 3):

You would need to use:

```
   QList<const MyInt*> myintarray;
```

Comment: Was going to say that you wouldn't want to save const pointers because you'd leak (due to delete not working on them).  But I looked it up, and to my surprise you can indeed delete a const pointer.  Not sure if I like it, but...one learns something new every day I guess!

Comment: Okay, if I did that, then will that object be mutable? 
I want to loop through that list and edit some values, but that wouldn't be possible because that will discard the 'const' qualifier. Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is telling you all you need to now - you're trying to store a `const T*` as a `T*` and implicit conversions from `const T*` to `T*` are not allowed.
Just leave out the `const` when `append()`ing.

Answer (score 0):

I would say you should just be passing a regular MyInt* into QList::append. The "const T&" refers to the pointer type--QList is promising not to reassign the pointers you provide.